# ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'uniform_real_distribution' with no type

Tags: c++

```
#ifndef _RNG_H
#define _RNG_H

#include <random>

class RNG {
public:
  RNG() :
    _generator(_default_seed) { }

  RNG(uint32_t seed):
    _generator(seed) { }

  double operator()();

private:
  std::mt19937 _generator;
  static std::uniform_real_distribution<> _urd;
  static const int _default_seed;
};

#endif // _RNG_H
```

I am trying to encapsulate the random number generator used with a wrapper class. But when trying to compile the above code I get the following error:

rng.h:37: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 'uniform_real_distribution' with no type

rng.h:37: error: invalid use of '::'

rng.h:37: error: expected ';' before '<' token

But I am just trying to follow the example as given in http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution

Comment: Cannot reproduce: http://ideone.com/7O6D2M Do you compile with `-std=c++11` support?

Comment: C (and C++) don't allow users to use `_Leading_underscore_capital` names; watch out with `_RNG_H`

Comment: I compiled with -std=c++0x. I am forced to use gcc 4.4.7 due to dependency problems.

Comment: @mariner: It's likely that your problems are from GCC 4.4.7 not fully implementing C++11.

Comment: @BillyONeal: Such identifiers aren't exactly *disallowed*. They're reserved to the implementation, which makes defining them in your own code undefined behavior. Typically the compiler won't complain as long as the identifier happens not to collide with anything. Bottom line: Changing `_RNG_H` to `RNG_H` is a good idea, but it's unlikely to be the cause of the observed error.

Comment: @Kieth: I never intended to claim that it was the cause of the observed error (that's why I made it a comment and not an answer)

Answer (score 1):

G++ 4.4.7 implements [Technical Report 1's random](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B_Technical_Report_1), not C++11's random.

That means that there is no `std::uniform_real_distribution` type.

You can write code that looks like this:

```
#include <random>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::random_device rng;
    double x = std::uniform_real<>()(rng);
    printf("%lf\n", x);
}
```

Althought I suspect that there is something wrong with it, since it's returning values much larger than the range [0, 1), which is what I understand the limit is supposed to be.

Answer (score 0):

```
#if defined __GNUC__
  #define GCC_VERSION (__GNUC__ * 10000 \
                           + __GNUC_MINOR__ * 100 \
                           + __GNUC_PATCHLEVEL__)
  #if GCC_VERSION < 40300
    #include <tr1/random>
  #else
    #include <random>
  #endif
#else
  #include <random>
#endif

#include <iostream>
#include <sys/types.h>

typedef std::mt19937                                        generator_t;
typedef std::uniform_real<double>                           distribution_t;
typedef std::variate_generator<generator_t, distribution_t> variate_t;

int main() {
    generator_t sparfun_rand;
    variate_t sparfun_rand_unif(sparfun_rand, distribution_t(0.0,1.0));
    distribution_t dist(0.0, 1.0);
    for (int i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
      std::cout << dist(sparfun_rand_unif) << std::endl;
    }
}
```

Got it working with gcc 4.4.7 with -std=c++0x flag.